# From SAS to R - proc sort nodupkey

Tags: r, duplicates, translate

I'm traslating a SAS script to R but I don't know how does SAS work...
I have this piece of code:

```
proc sort data=table 
(keep= Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4 Field5) 
out=table_nodup nodupkey;
by Field1 Field2 Field4;
run;
```

I don't know what the code will do and then I don't know how to translate it to R...any help? :)

Comment: This will output a dataset called `table_nodup` which will have only `Field1 - 5`. Duplicate values of `Field 1, Field 2, Field 4` will be removed so that there is only 1 row per `Field 1/2/4` combination.

Comment: and which value will it take from field3 and field5? the lowest one due to the sort?

Comment: Code conversion is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  You need to either ask what the code does as a [tag:sas] question, or if you know what the code does ask how to do (whatever it does) as an [tag:r] question. If you ask the former, please do some research first; you should be able to at least find the basics out with a quick search.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this paper](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/037-30.pdf) I'd say it can be described with `dplyr` as following:

```
library(dplyr)
table %>% 
    select(Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5) %>% 
    group_by(Field1, Field2, Field4) %>% 
    slice(1)
```

`select` is for SAS's `keep`, then `nodupkey` can be translated to grouping by `by` variables and taking the first occurrences. A good thing is that `slice` returns a dataframe that is already sorted by the groups that were used, so `arrange` is not needed.

Answer (score -1):

Given the data frame `table` :

```
 table<- table[,c(Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5)]#keep specific columns 
 table_nodup<-unique(table[with(data, order(Field1, Field2, Field4))])#orders the data based on the 3 columns and select unique rows
```

Comment: Ok, so first it selects the fields, then it sorts the table by the key and then it takes out duplicated datas by the key...and for fields 3 and 5 which value does it take? The lowest one due to the sort?

Comment: Gawwd I hate SAS :(